# Difference between setting ID directly and setting eloquent associate relation when saving a model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have two tables, `employees` and `employee types`.

`employees` has the following fields

- id (PK)
- employee_type_id (FK)
- name

and `employee_type` has the following fields,

- id (PK)
- title

My eloquent model functions are,

`Employee`

```
  class Employee extends Model {

    public function employeeTypes() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\EmployeeType');
    }
}
```

`EmployeeType`

```
class EmployeeType extends Model {
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to keep a relation.
While inserting I can follow these two methods:

1.Setting ID

```
 $emp = new Employee();
 $emp->employee_type_id = $request->type_id;
 $emp->name = $request->name;
 $emp->save();
```

2.Setting relation

```
$emp->employeeTypes()->associate(EmployeeType::findOrFail($request->employee_types_id));
$emp->name = $request->name;
$emp->save();
```

Both methods are working fine.

What is the difference between these two types of insertion?

Which is best method?

Comment: It depends on the context, just `Keep It Simple Stupid/KISS`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Before I compare the options, there is a third one:

Using `associate()` with just the id

```
$emp->employeeTypes()->associate($request->employee_types_id);
```

---

Now let's see what the advantages and disadvantages of the methods are:

#### 1. Setting the foreign key manually

- Pro: It's the simplest method
- Contra: You have to explicitly use the foreign key column name

#### 2. Using `associate()` with the model

- Pro: The relationship will be set automatically so you can use the model later without first fetching it from the database
- Pro: The name of the foreign key column doesn't matter (it only needs to be defined in the relationship declaration)
- Contra: An extra query is necessary to fetch the related model first

#### 3. Using `associate()` with just the id

- Pro: The name of the foreign key column doesn't matter (it only needs to be defined in the relationship declaration)
- Contra: The relationship won't be loaded after associating the id. A query will run when you access `$emp->employeeTypes`

---

I personally prefer to use `associate()` (basically all relationship methods, even if they aren't always necessary). If I already have the model I pass that, and otherwise I'll just use the id. You already have defined your relationship with foreign key etc, so you might as well use it.

Comment: thank you for giving very clear clarification between these methods. I would like to go with `associate()` with id :)

Comment: Very good explanation! I will go with using `associate()` as well. 

Comment: Method 2 is the only safe one as you check the parent model (still) exists. Data is more consistent and you can't "forge" children on future models if the request validation is weak. In case of asynchronous tasks, you could also have a situation where the Type is gone, leading to orphans.