# Laravel assign User ID when registering

Tags: laravel, initialization

I was creating a new User when Registering with Laravel PHP, this way:

```
User::create([
      'name'      => $data['name'],
      'surname'   => $data['surname'],
      'pass'      => encrypt('password')
      ])
```

It works perfect, but now I want to create an empty Business and assign it to him, like:

```
Business::create([
      'name'      => 'Change the name of your Business',
      'address'   => 'Introduce your address here',
      'owner_id'  => ?? // here would go this new user's ID
      ])
```

How can I assign the ID that this new user will have? He's not registered yet at this point to assing to it owner_id = Auth::user()->id. So how can I make it??
Thanks a lot!

Comment: laravel uses bcrypt() method to hash passwords.

Comment: Do you use eloquent relationships? If so you could also use `$business->owner()->associate($user);`. You can see the difference between setting the ID and associating [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309353/difference-between-setting-id-directly-and-setting-eloquent-associate-relation-w).

Answer (score 1):

The create method will return the created model instance, so you can save it like this:

```
$user = User::create([
  'name'      => $data['name'],
  'surname'   => $data['surname'],
  'pass'      => encrypt('password')
  ]);
```

and then:

```
Business::create([
  'name'      => 'Change the name of your Business',
  'address'   => 'Introduce your address here',
  'owner_id'  => $user->id
  ]);
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! =D
I didn't know the user is created after finishing its statement.
I had in mind.. as if I had to do user->save(); at some point and finish it all.

Thank you!